# TYPESCRIPT: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, return

newbie here with some ugly code. I'm still working on method encapsulation. I'm trying to make code that allows me to compare two input strings and return a boolean value of their "anagram" status, with the conditions shown below. I would greatly appreciate if somebody could provide me with a solution or workaround to the "function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include undefined". Any advice is welcome and appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
class Example {
  firstWord = prompt();
  secondWord = prompt();
  public isAnAnagram(firstWord: string, secondWord: string): boolean {
    if (firstWord && secondWord !== null) {
      const firstArray = firstWord.split("");
      const secondArray = secondWord.split("");

      // Show how the firstword and secondword have transformed into arrays
      console.log(firstArray, secondArray);

      let arrayPassed = true;
      if (
        firstArray.every((w) => secondArray.includes(w)) &&
        secondArray.every((w) => firstArray.includes(w))
      ) {
        // Show if first word passes anagram test through console
        console.log("Found all letters of " + firstWord + " in " + secondWord);
      } else {
        arrayPassed = false;
        // Show if first word does not pass anagram test through console
        console.log(
          "Did not find all letters of " + firstWord + " in " + secondWord
        );
      }

      return arrayPassed;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sarah! `public isAnAnagram(...)` is invalid syntax; TS/JS doesn't support `public`

Comment: @tbjgolden JS doesn't, but TS does...

Comment: Please fix formating, as of now, I think that you have too many ending braclets

Comment: @sarahMaio, i updated the indentation of your question and added `class` since that seemed to be what you were making (based on the use of `public`), but on second inspection i think i may have been wrong to make it a class since you never use `this`. If i messed up the code, please feel free to undo or redo my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start your function by checking this:

```
 if (firstWord && secondWord !== null) {
```

The code inside the if returns a boolean, but there's no `else` block, and no code after the `if`. So if code doesn't match the `if`, you'll be implicitly returning `undefined`. This contradicts what you told typescript the return type would be: `boolean`.

```
public isAnAnagram(firstWord: string, secondWord: string): boolean
```

To fix this, either add an `else` case and return a boolean:

```
else {
  return false
}
```

Or change the return type to allow you to return `undefined`.

```
public isAnAnagram(firstWord: string, secondWord: string): boolean | undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using try catch before your return.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).